# Typescript path aliases not resolved correctly at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig-paths

I'm running VS Code and I am currently trying to set up some aliases on my typescript project.

My dev setup rest on nodemon and ts-node, the code gets compiled to a dist folder.

So far, I succeeded to get Typescript Hero to manage the import with aliases:

[image: alias resolution vscode]

So far, my folder structure is:

```
.
└─┬ src
  ├──modules
  ├────Category
  ├────Ressource
  ├──shared
  ├────debug
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*": [
                "shared/*"
            ],
            "@modules/*": [
                "modules/*"
            ]
        },
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*.test.ts",
    ]
}
```

And this is the first alias import that fails.

```
//Server.ts file
import Print from '@shared/debug/Print.class';
import App from './App';

const MyApp: App = new App();

MyApp.ExpressApp.listen(MyApp.Config.ExpressPort, () => {
    Print.Log('Express server listening on port ' + MyApp.Config.ExpressPort);
});
```

However, I get an error:  *"Cannot find module '@shared/debug/Print.class'"* on "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ts-node ./src/server.ts". 
[image: CMD logs]

And this is where I stand.

Now, I've read some Q&A on SO, and it seems that even if I managed to make the aliases works while in dev, it would fail in production, as I'm running from Typescript src folder and my deliverable are built in dist ? If so, is there any way to remediate ? Many thanks

Comment: can you confirm you have a Print.class.ts file in the shared/debug folder

Comment: I do have such file, for now it’s only doing a console log on dev/staging environments.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem was situated on node path aliases resolution on runtime. Even if the typescript was executed on runtime by ts-node, the aliases couldn't be resolved by node as-is. (I think)

But this was only the tip of the iceberg. 
I'd encounter it then later with my jest setup, and on JS runtime.

I had to find a way, for every runtime I had, to interpret my aliases. There was a few npm packages but a lot of them required more declarations.

And I didn't want to declare my aliases in every config files I'd have and only depend on my tsconfig file.

After much testings, there was only two node modules to install [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) for typescript runtime execution on ts-node.
And [@ef-carbon/tspm](https://github.com/ef-carbon/tspm) to convert my aliases to the build destination.

```
npm i -D tsconfig-paths @ef-carbon/tspm
```

For ts-node, the script was modified as :

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/server.ts
```

For your js compiled, you only have to run :

```
ef-tspm
```

For jest, [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) is needed, I already had it but it wasn't properly configured. 
I used the built-in helper to set up my paths. 
My jest config file now looks like this :

```
//jest.config.js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json',
            diagnostics: {
                warnOnly: true,
            },
        },
    },
    clearMocks: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'node', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/src/' }),
    pathToJest: 'npm test',
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testMatch: null,
};
```

Here is, how my scripts look like in my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev:ts": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon",
    "dev:js": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run start:js",
    "staging": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging npm run start:js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run start:js",

    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=testing jest --runInBand",
    "test:debug": "npm run test --detectOpenHandles",

    "start:js": "npm run build && nodemon --config nodemon-js.json",
    "build": "npm run compile && npm run post:compile && npm run copyAssets",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "post:compile": "ef-tspm",
    "copyAssets": "copyfiles -e ./src/**/*.ts -e ./src/**/*sample* -e ./src/**/*.json -u 1 ./src/**/* ./dist/"
  },
```

Seeing how it goes, I'll probably add a grunt/gulp solution afterward. But for now, this is good enough.

Comment: ef-tspm looked promising, but it's now archived. might not be best option for those in 2022+

Comment: Follow [this PR](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/pull/1585) for integrated ts-node path mapping

Comment: Both OP and @Micah's suggestions didn't work for me. What **did** work was the build time tool [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias). After installing, I changed my build script to this and it just worked: `tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json`. For more details see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346203/8221175).

Answer (score 30):

I faced the same problem and CrazyYoshi solution is not worked properly in my case.

I fixed it with putting this code in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

After it do not forget to install `tsconfig-paths/register` module:

```
npm i -D tsconfig-paths
```

Documentation: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/paths/

Comment: didn't work in my case

Comment: This does not work, when I do build with ```tsc``` command using ```ts-node``` in production is not advisable. It works in dev.

Answer (score 15):

You're using `ts-node` and `nodemon` to run your code, so you should add this to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "ts-node": {
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
    }
}
```

And then install `tsconfig-paths/register` as a dev dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths
```

### References

- [Paths and baseUrl](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/paths/)
- [Path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Answer (score 11):

March 2023

Just spent literally hours trying to get this to work. In the end, I ended up ditching ts-node entirely and installing [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) which just worked straight out of the box.

Apparently, this is coming to ts-node eventually, although the PR kind of looks dead so who knows:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/pull/1585

In the mean time, if you really want to stick with ts-node you may find the following useful:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bleed-believer/path-alias

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1450#discussioncomment-1806115

Comment: This is the right solution, `tsx` worked out of the box!

Comment: Side note: **decorators are not supported** by tsx: https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx/issues/216. This is a big limitation if you're using libraries like routing-controllers and nestjs.

Comment: +1 ... saved me a lot of headache. i'm not using nestjs, just straightforward express.js low resource consuming app. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use the package called `module-alias` to solve this problem.

First, install it with yarn, npm or pnpm, choose one what you use.

Then, add same alias to your `package.json` just like:

```json
{
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@shared": "./src/shared",
    "@modules": "./src/modules"
  }
}
```

Finally, to import `module-alias/register` in your **first line**(that's important)!

```
import 'module-alias/register'
// ... your other code
```

This is the address of [`module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) You can refer to it.

I hope my answer will help you to solve it.

Comment: This answer is actually the best in 2022. Additionaly, you can also check this very nice [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-node-js-230803e3f200)

Answer (score 0):

I installed `tsc-alias` in my express js project to handle aliases paths with `nodemon`:

and it works for me correctly :).

`tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my `nodemon.json` file :

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "concurrently \"npx tsc && tsc-alias && ts-node dist/main.js\""
}
```

and this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "rest-mongoose",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx tsc && tsc-alias",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/main.js",
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.8",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

You can run your project on development mode with bottom command:
`npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify it:

- `tsc-alias` will fix `tsc`
- `tsconfig-paths/register` will deal with `ts-node` and `nodemon`.

The usage, as the others said, is simple. First, install it:

```bash
npm i -D tsc-alias tsconfig-paths
```

Then you can update your scripts to use them

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
    "watch": "nodemon --watch ./src --exec 'ts-node src/index.ts'"
  }
}
```

Other options are:

- `tsx`: replaces `tsc`.
- `ts-node-dev`: replaces `nodemon`
- node `--watch` flag: node v18.11 and above

Answer (score -1):

Easy: Just use tsx, works perfectly and requires zero setup.

```
npx tsx ./path-to-your-script
```