# How to resolve path issues with tsoa-generated routes and compiled TypeScript files?

Tags: typescript, express, tsoa

I am relatively new to TypeScript and the compilation process, so please bear with me if I am missing something obvious.

I have an express API written in TypeScript using tsoa decorators to generate docs from the code.

In my app the source code is located in /src, and then transpiled to /dist at build time.
tsoa automatically generates a routes file that is compiled to /dist/routes.js (tedious system btw).

The issue I am facing is that in the built `routes.js` file, all the controllers are referenced using the path `../src`.

This causes the application to fail when running from the compiled version (which is what I'll do once in production) unless I manually change the paths to reference the compiled files instead.

For example, to make the following controller work, I have to change the import statement in routes.js from:

```js
const LocationController_1 = require("./../src/controllers/LocationController");
```

to:

```js
const LocationController_1 = require("./controllers/LocationController");
```

Since the routes file is generated automatically by tsoa, it should not be manually modified.

However, I have followed the instructions in the documentation for tsoa and TypeScript thoroughly and have not been able to resolve the issue. I have also researched this issue and came across, but since tsoa handles the whole process of controller discovery, I cannot force it to use an alias for the path, tsconfig-paths can be another solution but I wasn't able to configure it properly.

Is there something that I am missing?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES6",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Here's what I've tried to with aliasing paths

```
 "paths": {
      "@controllers/": [
        "./src/controllers/*"
      ]
    }
```

In tsoa.json I've tried to use the alias to find the controllers

```
  "controllerPathGlobs": [
    "@controllers/*"
  ],
```

This does not find any controller.

I've also tried to use this in tsconfig

```
 "paths": {
      "../src/controllers": [
        "./controllers"
      ]
    }
```

I'm pretty sure something obvious is missing here...!

Thank you for your help, and I apologize for any confusion or mistakes in my explanation.

Comment: What was the problem with configuring aliases using tsconfig paths?

Comment: I've added some info to the question that should reply your answer

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to use the [`tsoa` configuration](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/getting-started.html#configuring-tsoa-and-typescript) to point to the transpiled controllers in the `dist` directory.

Try and modify your `tsoa.json` configuration like this:

```json
{
  "entryFile": "src/index.ts",
  "noImplicitAdditionalProperties": "throw-on-extras",
  "controllerPathGlobs": ["dist/controllers/**/*.js"],
  "spec": {
    "outputDirectory": "dist/swagger",
    "specVersion": 3
  },
  "routes": {
    "basePath": "/api",
    "routesDir": "dist/routes",
    "authenticationModule": "./src/auth/authentication"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ES2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

In this configuration, `tsoa` looks for controllers in the `dist/controllers` directory, not `src/controllers`.

That setup assumes that you will always compile your TypeScript files into JavaScript before running `tsoa`.
The full process would be something like:

- Compile TypeScript to JavaScript (`tsc`).
- Generate routes with `tsoa` (`npx tsoa routes`).
- Start your application (for instance, `node dist/index.js`).

If you need to keep your development workflow (running the app directly from TypeScript files), one option would be to have two different `tsoa.json` configurations - one for development (pointing to TypeScript files in `src`) and one for production (pointing to JavaScript files in `dist`). You can use `NODE_ENV` environment variable to choose the correct configuration.

While this is not the most convenient solution, it is a workaround that can unblock you until a better solution is found or `tsoa` improves its support for path aliases. Make sure to follow `tsoa`'s issue tracker and community for updates and potential solutions.

---

Regarding path aliases, see "[Typescript path aliases not resolved correctly at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60067281/6309)"

> Just spent literally hours trying to get this to work. In the end, I ended up ditching `ts-node` entirely and installing [`tsx`](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) which just worked straight out of the box.
>
> Side note: decorators are *not* supported by tsx: [issue 216](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx/issues/216). This is a big limitation if you're using libraries like routing-controllers and nestjs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to configure path aliases in your tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

This defines a path alias @controllers that maps to the src/controllers directory.

And you can try updating your tsoa.json file to the following:

```
{
  "controllerPathGlobs": ["@controllers/*"],
  ...
}
```

Hope this one helps you