# Vite Build Error: Cannot Find Module with Alias Import for Variables, Only Types

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I have a Vite project with the following files:

```js
// config.ts
import { foo } from '@root/baz'
import { Bar } from '@root/baz'
```

```js
// baz.ts
export const foo = 'foo'
export type Bar = 'foo'
```

When I start the application in dev mode, everything works as expected. However, when I run 'vite build,' I get the error "Cannot find module '@root/baz'."

If I modify the config file so that the variable "foo" is imported relatively, it works:

```js
// config.ts
import { foo } from './baz'
import { Bar } from '@root/baz'
```

It seems that I can import types via alias, but not variables. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60131288/10894961) answer your question?